# Cannot reach Apache through local network

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall

I just installed EasyPHP so as to have an Apache web server with PHP and everything included. This works like a charm when I access it by browsing to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/`, but unfortunately it fails when I go to `http://192.168.x.x:8888/` (where `x` is my computer address in my local network). In Chrome, I get the following error:

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

What I've tried:

- I *am* able to ping to my computer using `ping 192.168.x.x`.
- I've added an exception to Windows Firewall so as to let it pass requests to the 8888 port, to no avail.

Would anyone possibly know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add "Listen 192.168.x.x:8888" to Apache conf and edit VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
```

Comment: I changed the Listen directive to just `Listen 8888` and it was all working, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by the Apache settings for the directory where your files are kept.

Open `httpd.conf` and check the

```
<Directory "c:/where_is/easy_php_installed/www">
```

part. If the content is:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1`
```

change it to:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: And is the listen directive in the httpd.conf `Listen 8888`?

Comment: No it wasn't - sorry I'm a very beginner.

Comment: For Apache 2.4 users, comment out `Order` and `Allow` commands and add `Require all granted` in virtualhost conf file.